# Are google cookies which exist in chrome, firefox, ie browsers sent when some requests are made in phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, phantomjs

As far as I understand phantomjs is completely isolated exe process and it can't even get this data (cookies saved in browsers on user pc) to send when requests are made to google from phantomjs. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is a standalone browser. It doesn't use any stored cookies from the profiles of different browsers, just like any other browser. You wouldn't expect to open Firefox, go to a website, log in, then open Chrome, go the same website and be logged in, do you?